# Instantiating an ActionListener type object from an ActionListener interface

Tags: java, interface, anonymous-class

I want to ask a question about instantiating an ActionListener object.

I have written the following code as part of a beginner course on Java:

```
// anonymous classes
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TickTockAnonymous {
    private String tickMessage = "Tick...";
    private String tockMessage = "Tock...";

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        TickTockAnonymous t = new TickTockAnonymous();
        t.go();
    }

    private void go () {
        // create a timer that calls the Ticker Class at one second intervals
        Timer t = new Timer (1000, new ActionListener() {
            private boolean tick = true;

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) 
            {
                if (tick) 
                {
                    System.out.println(tickMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(tockMessage);
                }
                tick = !tick;
            }
        });
        t.start();

        // display a message box to prevent the program from terminating immediately
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Click OK to exit program");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This code works.

I'm a bit confused about this block of code:

```
Timer t = new Timer (1000, new ActionListener() {
            private boolean tick = true;

            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) 
            {
                if (tick)
                    // relevant code here continues
```

I know that I cannot instantiate an object from an interface - I must create an object from an interface and use the `extend` keyword to use the interface, much like a CS blueprint.

However, in the line

```
, new ActionListener() {
            // relevant code here continues
```

I haven't directly created an object that implements the ActionListener interface, although this appears to work.

The book I am reading states:

> The second parameter of the TimerClass constructor is an object that implements the ActionListener interface. This object is created here via an anonymous class. ActionListener is specified as the type for this class.

But I can't see how I've implemented it. I thought I initially created an object from an interface directly, which I realised was illegal.

How is this interface implemented?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if we consider the syntax of an anonymous class:

```
new ClassOrInterface() {};
```

the syntax expects the name of an existing class or Interface (to implement for the latter)

hence by doing

```
new ActionListener() {// code};
```

we are already implementing the ActionListener interface by default.